# How to get the posted "id=1&id=2" in action, in play2?

Tags: scala, http-post, playframework-2.0

I have a form which contains some rows, each has a checkbox in the leading. User can select some of them, then press "delete selected rows" button to submit.

The posted data looks like:

```
id=1&id=2&id=3
```

I want to get them in action, my code is:

```
def delete = Action { implicit request =>
   Form("id"->seq(nonEmptyText)).bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest, 
      ids => {
         println(ids)    // (!)
         for(id<-ids) deleteRow(id)
      }
   )
}
```

But I found the ids was always `List()`, an empty List.

I've checked the "Form samples" provided by play2, and found `seq(...)` should only worked with posted data with such format:

```
company sdfdsf
firstname   sdfds
informations[0].email   sdf@sdf.com
informations[0].label   wef
informations[0].phones[0]   234234
informations[0].phones[1]   234234
informations[0].phones[x]   
informations[1].email   sdf@sdf.com
informations[1].label   wefwef
informations[1].phones[0]   234234
informations[1].phones[x]   
informations[x].email   
informations[x].label   
informations[x].phones[x]
```

Please notice that there are many `[0]` or other indexes in the parameter names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using a `Form` helper in this case, you could (and probably want to) access the url-encoded content of the request body.

The way to do this is e.g.:

```
def delete = Action { implicit request =>
  request.body.asFormUrlEncoded match {
    case Some(b) =>
      val ids = b.get("id")
      for(id <- ids) deleteRow(id)
      Ok
    case None =>
      BadRequest
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a hard limitation in Play2, currently.

The whole form binding framework is based on translating from/to `Map[String,String]` and for both FormUrlEncoded and Json input this is accomplished by throwing away everything but the first value for every key.

I'm experimenting with changing everything over to `Map[String,Seq[String]]` but it's as yet unclear how compatible that approach can be. See https://github.com/bartschuller/Play20/tree/formbinding for the work in progress (branch will be force-pushed without warning).

Critique, API suggestions, and tests welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your posted data look like

```
id[0]=1&id[1]=2&id[2]=3
```

It should work.